# Rails last 100 years

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, select

How can I get a dynamic array of the last 100 years?

```
 def years_options
    (100.years.ago.to_date..Date.today).map{ |year| year.strftime("%Y") }
 end
```

returns some 36000 values as it is returning the `year` for every day between those two dates. How can I just get an array of the years?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you simply:

```
def years_options
    this_year = Date.today.year
    (this_year-100..this_year)
end
```